# Nested for loops in swift 3 for uibuttons title

Tags: for-loop, swift3, nested-loops, iboutletcollection

I have an outlet collection of UIButtons:

```
@IBOutlet var categoriesButtonLabels: [UIButton]!
```

each button has a different tag (set in the storyboard).

I want to change their titles filling with an array of strings (the categories which I retrieve somewhere else in my code from my FireBase database).

I tried something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
// Setting Category buttons labels
    for button in categoriesButtonLabels {
        for i in categories {
            button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

but it's getting just the last value of the categories array and setting the title the same for all the buttons...
What am I doing wrong?

For the sake of completeness:
This is my category array:

```
for (index, value) in categories.enumerated() {
print("\(index) = \(value)")
}
```

and outlet collection:

```
for (index, value) in categoriesButtonLabels.enumerated() {
print("\(index) = \(value)")
}
```

Output:

> categories string array is:0 = sports categories string array is:1 =
>   science categories string array is:2 = movies categories string array
>   is:3 = music categories string array is:4 = history
>
> Outlet UIButtons Collection is:0 = > Outlet UIButtons Collection is:1 =
>   > Outlet UIButtons Collection is:2 = > Outlet UIButtons
>   Collection is:3 = > Outlet
>   UIButtons Collection is:4 = >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inner loop:

```
for (i, button) in categoriesButtonLabels.enumerated() {
    button.setTitle("\(categories[i])", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm missing something... if I remove the inner loop, where will you get the [i] for categories?

Comment: fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb).

which is super strange since my categories array is populated correctly

Comment: Check the length of the 2 arrays and value of `i`. `categories` is too short

Comment: Well, I got it.
The problem is that the loading of data from FireBase takes a while.

Comment: So when my viewDidLoad starts, array of categories is still empty (nil) therefore the out of index error.
Where should I load data to avoid such kind of errors? 
By the way your answer was perfect (and it was my fault!!)

Comment: Set a default title for each button and in completion handler of Firebase query, add the loop cause you now have all the correct categories. You should never add an artificial delay to `viewDidLoad`